# overleaf always crashes in my chromium-browser

Tags: flash, adobe, chromium

I am writing some latex on the webpage http://overleaf.com and after around 10 minutes.

The error message:

```
user@lh:~$ chromium-browser --version
Using PPAPI flash.
 --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=
Chromium 62.0.3202.75 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04
```

My Adobe Flash Version: our Flash Version:

```
27.0.0.183
```

What can I do against?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. But it must something related to update the adobe flash: https://askubuntu.com/questions/562035/adobe-flash-plugin-is-vulnerable-outdated-in-14-04-but-there-is-no-update-in-fir